# Межпотоковое взаимодействие

Tags: многопоточность, java

Здравствуйте. Существует ли в джаве способ передачи сообщений другому потоку?
Очевидный вариант: класс со статическим BlockingQueue не предлагать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень сильно будет зависеть от поставленной задачи; кое-что, правда, можно понимать уже заранее. Для передачи *данных* между потоками необходимы как минимум две вещи:

1. Место (область памяти), где
       данные будут храниться, т.е.
       некоторый объект (объект модели
       данных, очередь, что угодно),
       выполняющий роль контейнера
2. Механизм извещения других потоков
       при совершении одним какого-то
       ключевого действия

Способ реализации первой части включает в себя стратегию управления данными, в том числе буферизацию, ограничение объема данных и т.п. Вообще говоря, контейнер при этом сам по себе может содержать минимум синхрозационных деталей или вообще не заботиться о синхронизации, полностью снимая с себя эту обязанность.

По второй части есть несколько вариантов, многие как раз из пакета `java.util.concurrent`.

Самый базовый вариант оттуда - использовать `Lock` и `Condition`: все потоки имеют общий доступ к объекту Condition, созданному с помощью `Lock.newCondition()` и один из них вызывает `Condition.signal()`, в то время когда другие заблокированы на `Condition.await()`. Есть еще более специфичные сигнальные объекты - `Semaphore` и `CountDownLatch` - в принципе, работают схожим образом. Кроме того, есть такая штука, как `Exchanger` - по сути, это синхронизированный контейнер(слот) для объекта, который любой поток может заменить на объект с другим содержимым (если предполагается именно *диалог* сообщений - это может быть неплохой вариант).

Ну и конечно `BlockingQueue` (уж не знаю, чем не понравилась) - сочетает в себе сразу готовую и первую часть, и вторую.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что требуется:

1. нужна ли буферизация,
2. стратегия обработки поступающих сообщений в случае превышения лимита,
3. требуется ли высокая производительность на многопоточной нагрузке,

По любому реализация будет вокруг Queue, или поищи неблокирующие алгоритмы.